# Removing MediaElement.js from Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, audio, mediaelement.js

On the page I have a button with several data attributes, title and audioURL. One click, I have some javascript that populates a modal window with the title, and simple html5 audio player with the data-audioURL in the src attribute. Once that is complete, I initialize MediaElement. On success, I play the audio.

When the user closes the modal window, I want to remove the MediaElement so that another button with a different title and audioURL can populate the audio player and then reinitialize MediaElement.  Currently, the code I have succeeds to stop the audio playback, but it doesn't destroy the player.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#closerLook" data-title="Song Title" data-audio="audio.mp3"><i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i> Hear a Sample</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="closerLook" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Audio Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3 id="cl-title" class="text-center"></h3>
        <audio id="audioSample" preload="meta" tabindex="0" controls><source src=""/></audio>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var me;

    $('#closerLook').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $('#audioSample').attr("src", "");
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var theTitle = button.data('title');
        var theAudio = button.data('audio');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('#cl-title').text(theTitle);
        $('#audioSample').attr("src", theAudio);
        loadPlayer();
    });


    $('#closerLook').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
        console.log(me);
        me.remove();
    });
});

function loadPlayer() {

    $('#audioSample').mediaelementplayer({
        audioWidth: '100%',

        success: function(mediaElement, originalNode, instance) {
            mediaElement.play();
            me = mediaElement;
        }
    });
}
```

I know I'm missing something in the hide.bs.modal function to properly remove the player, I just don't know what.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy"? You are removing it from the DOM by calling `remove()`, is that what you want?

Comment: I mean just what the MediaElement.js documentation implies. remove() -  Destroy the video/audio player instance :: https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: Ah, when you said "succeeds to stop the audio playback, but it doesn't destroy the player", I assumed you meant the audio element. What is `mejs.players[]` referencing? Looks like you're accessing an array without specifying an index?

Comment: sorry bout that... old version of trial and error, I uploaded a more recent attempt, still doesn't work.

Comment: The `me` you are assigning `mediaElement` to is not the same variable as the one declared inside DOM ready. The `me` you are assigning `mediaElement` to is an implied global. The one inside DOM ready is only in scope of it's parent function.

Comment: strange, if I do a console.log on the mediaElement inside the success, it returns the exact some thing.

Comment: Oh. You can move on('hide' .. to loadPlayer function and use var me only inside that scope..

Comment: move `var me` out of `document.ready`

Comment: Muhammad, can you put that into an answer. that makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: no it should work just move thee `var me` outside `doucment.ready` and it will work on the html element too. i just cehcked it

Comment: still nothing. the mediaElement will load properly, and will stop playback when I close the modal window, but when I relaunch the modal, the mediaElement initialization will not fire again. What exactly does remove() do if it does not remove the MediaElement from the page?

Comment: I just checked ME docs. Try to call instance.remove()

Comment: see the answer i added @Murphy1976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `var me` out of `document.ready` and initialize the variable inside the `success` function with `instance` see the working example below

```js
var me;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#closerLook').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
    let button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    let theTitle = button.data('title');
    let theAudio = button.data('audio');
    let modal = $(this);
    modal.find('#cl-title').text(theTitle);
    //setSrc (src)
    $('#audioSample').attr("src", theAudio);
    loadPlayer();
  });


  $('#closerLook').on('hide.bs.modal', function(event) {
    console.log('removing');
    //me.pause();
    me.remove()
  });
});

function loadPlayer() {
  $('#audioSample').mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: '100%',
    error:function(mediaElement, originalNode, instance) {
    console.log('error');
    },
    success: function(mediaElement, originalNode, instance) {
      console.log('success');
      console.log(mediaElement)
      instance.play();
      me = instance;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.7/mediaelementplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/4.2.7/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#closerLook" data-title="SoundHelix" data-audio="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"><i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i> Hear a Sample</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="closerLook" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Audio Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3 id="cl-title" class="text-center"></h3>
        <audio id="audioSample" preload="meta" tabindex="0" controls><source src=""/></audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: that's what it was. I was referencing mediaElement instead of instance. Works great now. Thanks Muhammed.

Comment: you are welcome @Murphy1976 , glad it worked for you , have a good day ahead